# Set selected row from backing bean in primefaces datatable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using primefaces datatable with clickable rows and I need to find way how to set selected row from backing bean.

There is my datatable definition:

```
<p:dataTable id="cablePathTable" var="cablePath" value="#{commonTableBean.cableLazyModel}" rows="100"
         selectionMode="single" selection="#{commonTableBean.selectedCablePathTblRow}" 
         rowIndexVar="rowIndex"  widgetVar="datatableVar"
         emptyMessage="---">  
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" process="@this" update=":form:portFieldset" />

<p:column headerText="No">  
    <h:outputText value="#{cablePath.column1}" />  
</p:column>
<p:column headerText="Port A">  
    <h:outputText value="#{cablePath.column4}" />  
</p:column>
<p:column headerText="Port B">  
    <h:outputText value="#{cablePath.column5}" />  
</p:column>
```

I have tried following approach, but with no success.
In backing bean I have added method:

```
public void test(){
    DataTable dataTable = (DataTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("form:cablePathTable");
    dataTable.setRowIndex(2);
}
```

And I have added test butoon to the XHTML page:

```
<p:commandButton process="@this" update=":form:cablePathTable" value="set2row" action="commonTableBean.test"/>
```

But nothig is changed on the datatable, selection didn't change...

Please any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just set the value behind `selection="#{commonTableBean.selectedCablePathTblRow}"`.

```
public void test(){
    selectedCablePathTblRow = cablepath;
}
```

Comment: D'Oh! It was THAT easy! Thank you very much!

Comment: ist it possible to do it when the page is shown for? Without pressing a command button?

Comment: Just set the value in bean's (post)constructor.

Comment: @BalusC, thank you. Your solution works perfect but when I use table with pagination and when I selecting row from next page table not switching. Is there solution for this except changing page by using paginator object from javascript? I've used it and it was very slow and buggy. Thank you!